# Access Parent object's field in Child object using formula field

Tags: formula-field, childrecords, parent

I have a Account Test1 with Address Line 1, City and State.
I have another Account Test2 with Address Line1.
Test1 is the parent of Test2.
In Case object,  i have a field where I am populating value of Test2 as name and Address Line1.
I want to merge Address Line-1, City and State in one of the fields of Case object.
Can we do this using formula field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can look to parent in formula fields. It would be simple:-

[image]

You would like to read :- [What Is a Cross-Object Formula?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=5)